# Adding a Layer from URL to ArcGIS Online with an API key in header

Tags: arcgis-online, api

I am working with a vendor to get some realtime locations that they have posted as an API through their product added to an ArcGIS Online layer.

The API requires you to pass a key through after the call is made in a header. I have tried to pass in additional parameters

[image]

When I click add file from URL there is an option to add in parameters and I have attempted to pass in an "Authorization" with the API key, but it always shoots back an error. 
[image]

Is it possible to add in an API key this way through ArcGIS online without using the ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Comment: you need CORS enabled > https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/cors/

Comment: Would suggest you use token authentication https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/core-concepts/security-and-authentication/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can map this API feeds as a feature layer right away. https://docs.goswift.ly/api-reference/real-time/getrealtimeagencykeygtfsrtvehiclepositions says this API returns Google Protocol Buffer format (PBF), and as far as I know there is no direct facility in AGOL to have a feature layer up and running by that source. In fact, if you need real-time flow of the tracked features, you need to run a https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/get-started/windows/what-is-arcgis-geoevent-server.htm. This thread might be helpful, https://community.esri.com/thread/224984-publish-gtfs-realtime-feed-through-arcgis-onlineenterprise.

If you want to do this without GeoEvent server, you can have a look at this, https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=a0514b345e2f45e3a7230db84485280d. Although this one uses

> some JS code running in a Lamda function on Amazon Web Services and polls the API every 30 seconds

to update the layer (so not necessarily real-time).

Comment: While i am frustrated that I cannot end up serving up this myself. The dev in me is excited about finally having a reason to explore lambda!!! Thanks for the response.